# jQuery multi action button

Tags: javascript, jquery

> I have a button. I click 3 times on
>   this button. I want show a yellow box
>   on first click, and hide the yellow
>   box and show a blue box instant of
>   that on second click , and hide blue
>   box and show a red box instant of blue
>   box on third click.

Is it possible with jQuery? How??

Comment: Do you want to cycle back to the start afterward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) method, which takes multiple functions as parameters and executes one for each click (*in sequence*)

example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/4qsq4/

Keep in mind that this is a bit brute solution. If you could provide some of your HTML structure we could possibly automate this more.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `.toggle()` can deal with any amount of handlers

Answer (score 1):

[Another realisation](http://jsfiddle.net/NBMe9/).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4xBmc/